# The probability of going bankrupt

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process, gambling

The question looks like a gambling problem. But I am not sure whether it is the same or similar to gambler's ruin problem.

Assume I have wealth $W_t$. At each step $t$, I encounter a random shock $x_t\in[0,\infty)$ drawn from the same distribution with continuous differentiable cdf $G(x)$. If $x_t\ge W_t$, I go bankrupt, otherwise I survive. Conditional on surviving, my wealth at the next step is
$$
W_{t+1}=W_t-x_t+w
$$
$w>0$ is my risk-less income.
The question is whether I will go bankrupt almost surely if $t$ goes to forever. If not, in such model, what is the necessary and sufficient condition for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "$I_t$" means "$x_t$", I think that if your "shock" is drawn from a positive distribution with mean $m$ and variance $v$ such that $m > w$ or ( $m = w$ and $v > 0$ ) or $v = \infty$, then almost surely you will go bankrupt, and in all other cases the probability of going bankrupt will be strictly less than 1. I think you should try proving this case by case.

Comment: So you mean that if variance is bounded, then mean of $x$ is no less that $w$ is kind of necessary and sufficient condition of bankruptcy, no?

Comment: No that's not what I said. Strictly less than 1 does not mean 0. Also, almost surely is not the same as surely.

Comment: Sure, the probability cannot be zero. My previous claim should be " if variance is bounded, then $E(x)\ge w $ is necessary and sufficient condition of almost surely go bankruptcy" Correct? Also, is there a hint of the proof? It has a complicated iterative structure, which makes me confused.

Comment: @AndyXu: Ok if you follow the condition I gave, you also need $v > 0$, otherwise obviously if $m = w$ then bankruptcy isn't possible (In my answer I assumed you get both the shock and income at the same time, otherwise you also have to split cases into $m \ge W_0$ and $m < W_0$). You can use Chebyshev's inequality on the sum of the shocks.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I suspect that Chebyshev's Inequality can only help me to prove that when $v>0$ and $m\ge w$, then the probability of go bankruptcy will converge to one. But I'm really interested in the other direction - When $m<w$ and $v$ is positive but finite, why the probability of go bankruptcy is strictly less than one. Thanks again!

Comment: @AndyXu: It should work for that case too. The mean after $k$ steps is $k(w-m)$ and the probability that the real value is $d$ away from that is bounded by $\frac{v}{d^2}$. Choosing the appropriate $d$ and summing over all steps gives a series that converges iff $v < \infty$.

Comment: I think your instruction is promising, but I am still not sure about. After $k$ steps, the variance is enlarged by $k$ times, so the bound in Chebyshev's Inequality becomes $\frac{kv}{d^2}$. $d$ should be linear in $n$. So the the summation of the series will be similar to $1+1/2+1/3...$ which is unbounded.

Comment: Oh so sorry I was careless. You're right so we can't just sum everything up. I'll think about it again, but I'm quite sure it is correct and there is a simple explanation.

Comment: I agree with you.  Maybe just enlarge every term too much. Thank you for your kind help!